# Sqlite get next record or first if at end

Tags: sql, objective-c, sqlite

I have a bunch of questions in a sqlite database and want to get the next one each time a question is requested. When I've gone through each question, I want to start over from the beginning. One way would be to save the the largest ID and then set the currentIndex back to the lowest ID before each query... but if would be nice to do this in the query.

I can get the next by this query:

```
@"SELECT * FROM question WHERE id > %i ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1", currentIndex)
```

Is it possible to check in the query if there's no next record with a higher ID, and then start from the beginning with the lowest ID?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query gets both the next and the first record, and then returns the first one that actually exists:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM question
      WHERE id > %i
      ORDER BY id
      LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM question
      ORDER BY id)
LIMIT 1
```

Alternatively, you could adjust the `id` limit:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM question
WHERE id > CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                             FROM question
                             WHERE id > %i)
                THEN %i
                ELSE -1
           END
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the first one (the lowest id)

```
@"SELECT * FROM question ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1"
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, however it's not quite what I'm looking for. I updated the question for clarifications. thanks